# Can't work when antd Dropdown child is a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

```
import { Dropdown, Button } from 'antd';
import { memo } from 'react';
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';
const headerMeau: MenuProps['items'] = [
  {
    key: '1',
    label: 'test'
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    label: 'test2'
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    label: 'test3'
  }
];
const A = function () {
  return <Button>111</Button>;
};
const BookSpace = memo(() => {
  return (
      <Dropdown menu={{ items: headerMeau }} placement="bottomLeft" trigger={['click']}>
        <A></A>
        {/* {A()} */}
      </Dropdown>
  );
});

BookSpace.displayName = 'BookSpace';

export default BookSpace;
```

It doesn't work when it is < A >  < / A >

It normal when it is {A()}

expected:when the child is a React Component it's normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgd5I.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Dropdown` component is the container for `Button` component and the actual `Menu`.

When you write a custom wrapper for `Button`, `Dropdown` doesn't know what to do with it. Because it is not a `Button` component anymore, it is a custom `A` component that wraps some JSX or `Button` components.

But when you do `{A()}` it returns the actual `Button` component of AntD and it works as intended.